# Calculate running difference between two columns in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, window-functions

I have data in two tables as below

Table 1 :

```
Material |Ordr Qty 
---------|---------
abcd     |4253
```

Table 2 :

```
Material | Stck Qty 
---------|---------
abcd     |1000
abcd     |2000
abcd     |2000
```

Expected Output :

```
Material |Ordr Qty |Stck Qty |Column D
---------|---------|---------|---------
abcd     |4253     |1000     |3253
abcd     |4253     |2000     |1253
abcd     |4253     |2000     |-747
```

Logic for column D is like

```
4253-1000 = 3253
3253-2000 = 1253
1253-2000 = -747
```

*LAG(ordr qty - stck qty,1,0)over (ORDER BY material)-stck qty*

I am trying above LAG function and getting below output

```
abcd    4253    1000    -1000
abcd    4253    2000    1253
abcd    4253    2000    253
```

Let me know how to achieve the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a window `sum()` rather than `lag()`:

```
select t1.*, t2.stck_qty,
    t1.ordr_qty - sum(t2.stck_qty) over(partition by material order by t2.id)
from t1
inner join t2 using(material)
order by material, t2.id
```

To get a stable result, you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows in `t2`: I assumed `id`.